# When considering degenerate states in energy bands of a semiconductor, how to use Joyce-Dixon approximation?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

> For non degenerate semiconductors, the physics seems well known, for example, the electron or hole concentrations are simple formula.
>   $$n(T) = N_{c}\cdot e^{\frac{E_{F}-E_{c}}{k_{B}\cdot T}}$$
>   $$p(T) = N_{v}\cdot e^{\frac{E_{v}-E_{F}}{k_{B}\cdot T}}$$
>   They're also relate by the law of mass action, and you can even write the equations above in terms of the intrinsic Fermi level and concentration.

What to do with a degenerate semiconductor? For example, what if you got a heavily doped p-type semiconductor and it has that $E_{F} = E_{v}$? What would happen in the other band?

I've recently started reading about the Joyce-Dixon approximation for this cases, but I haven't been able to understand how it can be exactly use to obtain the density of holes, for example.

> $$\frac{E_{v}-E_{F}}{k_{B}\cdot T} = ln(\frac{p}{N_{v}}) + \frac{p}{N_{v}\cdot \sqrt{8}} + ...$$
>   For holes.
>   Solving the complete Fermi-Dirac integral for the hole concentration I got $p(T) = 1.30645\cdot 10^{21}\cdot T^{\frac{3}{2}}$